# Can "as well as" be used in "A, B as well as C" structure?

Tags: phrase-usage

> The newspaper has various segments covering domestic and international
>   financial news, articles analyzing major economic policies and
>   business administration cases, as well as industry market information.

Can "as well as" be used in this way? 
I think "as well as" can be used in structures as "A and B as well as C" and "A as well as B and C" rather than "A, B as well as C".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think "as well as" can be used in structures as "A and B as well as C" and "A as well as B and C" rather than "A, B as well as C".

You are correct — the sentence you cited is incorrect. Whenever you see an "as well as X" clause, if you remove it, the remaining part of the sentence should be still be a complete sentence. Here it is not.